# Inseting data in database over AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok so I tried to do this in an easier way to break it into pieces and then to solve each piece but no luck. Can you help me I don't get any errors but just nothing happens. What I want is to insert data of admin in database over AJAX.PHP code works fine when it is without AJAX and I have no errors in console.

This is my HTML :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form  method="post" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id='username' type='text' value='username'/> 
    <input id='password' type='password' value='password'/>                         
    <input id="submit_value" type="button" name="submit_value" value="">
</form>
```

This is my JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_value").onclick = submitAction;

function submitAction()
{
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "insertAdmin.php",
            data: "username="+ username + "&password="+ password,
            success: function(){
                $("#frmProduct").fadeOut();
                $("#frmProduct").fadeIn();
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

And this is my php :

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("bazait", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO administrators ( namea, passa) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Successfully sent Email address.";

mysql_close($con); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `submitAction()` executed? Do `console.log(username);` or `console.log(password);` output anything?

Comment: Yes it output what I enter. @showdev

Comment: Is your `success` handler executed? What is the returned result? Maybe there's a PHP or MySQL error? This is a general attempt to troubleshoot because I [can't reproduce a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jqs02vjc/) with your HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like there's an extra `}` at the end of your PHP file. Could that be the problem?

Comment: YEEES THE STUPID BRACKET WAS THE PROBLEM. Thank you very much. I don't know how did it got there because I have tested these scripts separately. @showdev